# xmllint only selects first element

Tags: xpath, xmllint

I would like to extract the text of every `<id>`element with `xmllint` into a text file.

```
<rss>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <id>111</id>
            <description>text 1</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>222</id>
            <description>text 2</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>333</id>
            <description>text 3</description>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Each element should be on a separate line in the text file, like this:

```
111
222
333
```

I'm already getting stuck at selecting all elements. For some reason my `xmllint` command only returns the first element.

```
xmllint test.xml --xpath "string(//id)"
```

I've tried so many variations of that `--xpath` statement, but can't seem to figure it out.

(I don't know if it is relevant, but I'm using `xmllint` on OS X)

Comment: Try `"//id/text()"` instead or `//id/string()`

Comment: @Andersson `"//id/text()"`works, `//id/string()`doesn't. Thanks !! Do you know why my initial statement doesn't work?

Comment: `//id/string()` simply intend to return you the string representation for each node while `string(//id)` - only the string of first node found in DOM. You can also try this option `//item/string(./id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmllint --shell test.xml <<< `echo 'cat //id/text()'` > out.txt